# Perl DBI Can't work out what driver to use

Tags: mysql, perl, driver, dbi

So I am attempting to connect to a database on an end device from one of my servers, however I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't connect to data source '<user>' because I can't work out what driver to use (it doesn't seem to contain a 'dbi:driver:' prefix and the DBI_DRIVER env var is not set) at <script> line 18
```

My lines of code are the following. I removed some private information of course.

```
my $sHDS = shift || "<host>";
my @rows;
my $cust = '<customer name>';
my $dsn = 'dbi:Sybase:' . $sHDS;
my $user = '<user>';
my $pass = '<password>';

my $hDb = DBI::connect($dsn, $user, $pass)
or die "Can not connect to ICM Database $DBI::errstr";
```

Anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Not a `mysql` question. Use that tag with question that are specifically about MySQL, not just any database question.

Comment: if problems persist after fixing your function call ( see answer ), be sure to check the docs at http://search.cpan.org/~mewp/DBD-Sybase-1.15/Sybase.pm#Connecting_to_Sybase. They mention you may have to set an environment variable, which I do not see in your script ( perhaps rightly so )

Answer (score 9):

The correct call has the format

```
DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password)
```

which is subtly but significantly different from

```
DBI::connect($dsn, $user, $password)
```

The first call is equivalent to the call

```
DBI::connect( 'DBI', $dsn, $user, $password )
```

and the `connect` function in `DBI` actually expects your dsn to be specified in the 2nd argument it receives.